# How do I make customizations to elementary OS Loki?

Tags: themes, tweak-tool

I guess the elementary-tweaks project is shut down and won't be getting any updates. Is there any alternative to make customizations on various fronts to the brand new elementary OS Loki?

Answer (score 0):

You can still install elementary-tweaks for Loki trough philip.scott's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~philip.scott/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-tweaks

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install elementary-tweaks
```